# Deeper meaning of Bat Shlomo midrash

Tags: midrash, agada-stories-legends, king-solomon

Do any commentaries elucidate any deeper meaning into the story of Bat Shlomo in the tower (found here: [The Medrash About Shlomo HaMelech's Daughter](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/116969/the-medrash-about-shlomo-hamelechs-daughter?rq=1) )

Obviously the Pashut message is that Gd runs everything and can make anything that He wants happen. But what’s the deeper meaning, and what does everything symbolize?

Comment: Looks more like a Jewish fairy tale than anything else.